# Type mismatch returning an observable with fromCallable

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

The following code does not compile:

```
override fun storeConnections(connections: List<Connection>): Observable<List<Connection>> =
    Observable.fromCallable<List<Connection>> {
        appDao.storeConnections(connections.map {
                            mapper.toDb(it)})
        
        
    }
```

The line with appDao.storeConnections indicates the following error:

> Required List!
>
> Found Unit

The storeConnections is done using Room:

```
@Dao
interface RoomDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    fun storeConnections(linkedInConnection: List<LinkedInConnectionEntity>)

}
```

The storeConnections is called from my rx stream:

```
val startPositions = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(0)

startPositions.flatMap { startPos -> App.context.repository.getConnections(startPos) }
    .flatMap { connections -> Observable.fromCallable(App.context.repository.storeConnections(connections)) }
    .doOnNext { ind -> startPositions.onNext(ind + 1) }
    .subscribe({ ind -> println("Index $ind") })
```

How do I properly implement this fromCallable?

Comment: it's difficult to say unless you specify what this fun should be doing. Why would `storeConnections` return an obervable? What is it observing?

Comment: @TimCastelijns That's the problem. storeConnections is returning nothing. But I need to wrap it in an observable in order to push it down the stream. So maybe my question is how to wrap an API call with an Observable when that api call returns nothing. Most of the samples I've seen all return something from an api. But this one doesn't

Comment: *I need to wrap it in an observable in order to push it down the stream.* can you clarify?

Comment: What does the function `mapper.toDb(it)` return?

Comment: I updated my question and have shown the code that calls storeConnections. It is called with a fromCallable in a flatMap which requires an Observable.

Comment: @DiegoMagdaleno it returns a `List<LinkedInConnectionEntity>`

Comment: @DiegoMagdaleno toDB just converts one from one class to another. You can ignore that. That part works fine and is only used as a parameter for the storeConnections function.

Answer (score 0):

Given your reply to your question:

> storeConnections is returning nothing. But I need to wrap it in an observable in order to push it down the stream. So maybe my question is how to wrap an API call with an Observable when that api call returns nothing.

I will answer how you can wrap it in an observable in order to push it down the stream:

```
        .flatMap {
                connections -> 
                    App.context.repository.storeConnections(connections)
                        .andThen(Observable.just(connections))
        }
```

Given that storeConnections returns a Completable:

```
    override fun storeConnections(connections: List<Connection>): Completable =
        Completable.fromAction {
            appDao.storeConnections(connections.map { mapper.toDb(it) } )
        }
    }
```

If storeConnections returns "nothing", you could simply move the Completable.fromAction to your stream:

```
        .flatMap {
                connections -> 
                    Completable.fromAction { App.context.repository.storeConnections(connections) }
                        .andThen(Observable.just(connections))
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

The key to getting it to work is using this:

```
return@fromCallable connections
```

So this is the corrected code:

```
override fun storeConnections(connections: List<Connection>): Observable<List<Connection>> =
    Observable.fromCallable<List<Connection>> {

        appDao.storeConnections(connections.map {
            mapper.toDb(it)
        })

        return@fromCallable connections
    }
```

And the rx stream that calls it:

```
val startPositions = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(0)

    startPositions.flatMap { startPos -> App.context.repository.getConnections(startPos) }
        .flatMap {
                connections -> App.context.repository.storeConnections(connections)
        }
        .doOnNext {
                connections -> startPositions.onNext(startPos++)
        }
        .subscribe({ ind -> println("Index $ind") })
```